# App crashes when Web View oritentation changes then back button is pressed

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception, android-webview

I am developing an Android Application and am noticing a minor bug with my WebViewerActivity. When I open up a URL through Web View then change the orientation of the device, the orientation changes appropriately. However, when I then pressed the back button on the Android Device, it causes the App to crash. I am not sure what is causing this problem and would appreciate any suggestions.

The back button is able to run fine when the orientation is not changed.

**WebViewerActivity**

```
public class WebViewerActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_web_viewer);
    final TextView setHeader = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.directoryHeader);
    Intent intent = getIntent();

    setHeader.setText(intent.getStringExtra("header"));
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);

    WebView webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
    webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
    webView.setInitialScale(1);
    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
    webView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
    webView.setScrollBarStyle(WebView.SCROLLBARS_OUTSIDE_OVERLAY);
    webView.setScrollbarFadingEnabled(false);
    webView.loadUrl(intent.getStringExtra("url"));

    intent.removeExtra("url");
    intent.removeExtra("header");
}

 @Override
    public boolean onSupportNavigateUp() {
        onBackPressed();
        return true;
    }
}
```

**AndroidManifest**

```
<activity
        android:name=".activities.WebViewerActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_web_viewer"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"
        android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize|keyboardHidden"/>
```

**Exception**

```
11-20 18:50:24.612 23122-23122/com.russwilkie.metrostatemobile E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                             java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.russwilkie.metrostatemobile/com.russwilkie.metrostatemobile.activities.ListViewLinkActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2180)
                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.handleRelaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3692)
                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:141)
                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1240)
                                                                                 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
                                                                                 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
                                                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                                                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
                                                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
                                                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
                                                                                 at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
                                                                              Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
                                                                                 at com.russwilkie.metrostatemobile.activities.ListViewLinkActivity.setListViewValues(ListViewLinkActivity.java:74)
                                                                                 at com.russwilkie.metrostatemobile.activities.ListViewLinkActivity.onCreate(ListViewLinkActivity.java:41)
                                                                                 at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)
                                                                                 at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2144)
                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230) 
                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.handleRelaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3692) 
                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:141) 
                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1240) 
                                                                                 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
                                                                                 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137) 
                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041) 
                                                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
                                                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511) 
                                                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793) 
                                                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560) 
                                                                                 at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: share the exception stack trace, please

Comment: Hi @MateusGondim, I updated my question

Answer (score 0):

Added this to your `AndroidManifest.xml`

```
<activity android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait">
```

It will lock your view to portrait. So the orientation is lock to Portrait.